# Simple logic implication question

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic

Suppose I know that $$A \iff B$$ and $$ B \implies C $$

**Can I conclude that $A \land C \iff B$ ?**

It seems intuitively true, but I'm not sure if there is a nice way to show it.

Comment: Since $B\to A$ and $B\to C$, $B\to A\wedge C$. Since $A\wedge C\to A$ and $A\to B$, $A\wedge C\to B$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one maybe a little more complicated. $A \iff B$ means that you can substitute $A$ into  $B \implies C$ thus you have.

$A \implies C$  with this you can conclude $A \land C \iff A$

by subsituting the second $A$ with $B$ you get $A \land C \iff B$

Answer (score 2):

$
\def\fitchproof#1#2{\begin{array}{|l}#1 \\ \hline #2\end{array}}
$

$\fitchproof{
1. A \Leftrightarrow B\\
2. B \Rightarrow C
}{
\fitchproof{
3. A \land C
}{
4. A \quad \land Elim \ 3\\
5. B \quad \Leftrightarrow Elim \ 1,4
}\\
\fitchproof{
6. B}
{
7. A \quad \Leftrightarrow Elim \ 1,6\\
8. C \quad \Rightarrow Elim \ 2,6\\
9. A \land C \quad \land Intro \ 7,8
}\\
10. (A \land C) \Leftrightarrow B \quad \Leftrightarrow Intro \ 3-5,6-9}$

Comment: Nice formatting.

Comment: Thank you :) Could you give a small pointer on how to read this though? I am not familiar with the formatting.